# gactions not working - "caller does not have permission"

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to create a duplicate app on two of my email accounts. On one of them, the app can be updated using 'gactions update', however, on the other this returns with the following error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't fetch versions
ERROR: The caller does not have permission
```

I looked at the documentation for 'gactions', however, nothing I found seems to indicate that it only works for one google account. It is imperative that this app work with my other account. Is there any way to give the other account permission so I can update the action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gactions creates a "creds.data" file with the credentials of the account when gactions was used for the first time. You can only use that with one account at a time. Alternatively, you can clone your app code and install gactions in each of these with their own credentials.

Comment: thanks, I was able to delete the creds.data file and link the account I needed to. Thanks!